# Python scene change detection

Tags: python, video, video-processing

I am wondering if anyone has any experience with Python and video processing. Essentially, I would like to know if there are any libraries that would allow me to do scene detection in a video? If not, are there any that can allow me to split the video up into a series of frames and let me mess about with the pixels?

Thanks!

Comment: [PySceneDetect](https://github.com/Breakthrough/PySceneDetect) (open source) is a scene detection program I am developing which uses the OpenCV-Python bindings.  I've also posted a tutorial [on doing threshold-based scene detection](http://www.bcastell.com/tech-articles/pyscenedetect-tutorial-part-1/), again with Python; that should give you a good starting point for parsing videos with Python/OpenCV.

Comment: https://github.com/Breakthrough/python-scene-detection-tutorial

Answer (score 4):

[OpenCV](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/) has Python bindings; I don't think it has any scene boundary algorithms / functions built it, but you can definitely use it to write your own.

Answer (score 3):

You can use FFmpeg to do the scene detection and obtain the change frames and their timestamps. The command can be combined with a python script and you can modify it according to your use case.

You can simply use the command:

```
ffmpeg inputvideo.mp4 -filter_complex "select='gt(scene,0.3)',metadata=print:file=time.txt" -vsync vfr img%03d.png
```

This will save just the relevant information in the time.txt file like below and also save the shot change images in order:

```
frame:0    pts:108859  pts_time:1.20954
lavfi.scene_score=0.436456
frame:1    pts:285285  pts_time:3.16983
lavfi.scene_score=0.444537
frame:2    pts:487987  pts_time:5.42208
lavfi.scene_score=0.494256
frame:3    pts:904654  pts_time:10.0517
lavfi.scene_score=0.462327
frame:4    pts:2533781 pts_time:28.1531
lavfi.scene_score=0.460413
frame:5    pts:2668916 pts_time:29.6546
lavfi.scene_score=0.432326
```

The frame is the serial number of the detected shot change from the starting. Also, choose your threshold value (here 0.3) appropriately for your use case to get correct outputs